# rbhive ~ 0.6.0 gem breaking can can roles in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hive, cancan

When I added  gem 'rbhive', '~> 0.6.0' to Gemfile, it breaks the system with roles.
I am using rails 4.0.3 and Ruby 2.1.2. Error line is:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 374ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_name' for Role:Class):